# Navigate to method declaration in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following MVP architecture.
So I have lots of methods declared in my interfaces.
I am able to navigate to the method implementation with `ctrl+alt+mouseclick` or `ctrl+alt+B`
But I want to do the reverse. I need to go to the method declaration in the interface.

I've checked settings keymap and googled it, but there's no precise answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an icon on a gutter to go to base/interface method [image]

[Also](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html) `Go to super-method/super-class` is Control + U

Comment: Wow ! How I missed it ! :( Thanks for the prompt response !